# How to force CMake CXX and CC on Mac Yosemity?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake

I have `clang-omp` installed via brew. and I have executed `xcode-select --install` command. I am able to compile my project with OpenMP with it using `Unix Makefiles`. Yet I want to use Xcode for development. I tried all I could:

```
$export CC=/usr/local/bin/clang-omp
$export CXX=/usr/local/bin/clang-omp++
$CC="/usr/local/bin/clang-omp" CXX="/usr/local/bin/clang-omp++" cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/local/bin/clang-omp" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/local/bin/clang-omp++" -G "Xcode" ..
```

The problem is that CMake sets CXX to mac default:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.5.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
```

So how to force CXX and CC compiler paths on mac to Cmake?

Comment: One of your three ways should, I don't see a problem. What's your CMake version? Does this happen with a minimal CMake/C++ project, too? Have you cleared the CMake cache?

Comment: Cleaned up CMake cache; on CMake 3.6; Gonna try minimal now...